# How can I find out which index is out of range?

Tags: python, exception, index-error

In the event of an IndexError, is there a way to tell which object on a line is 'out of range'?

Consider this code:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]

x, y = get_values_from_somewhere()

try:
   a[x] = b[y]
except IndexError as e:
   ....
```

In the event that `x` or `y` is too large and `IndexError` gets caught, I would like to know which of `a` or `b` is out of range (so I can perform different actions in the `except` block).

Clearly I could compare `x` and `y` to `len(a)` and `len(b)` respectively, but I am curious if there is another way of doing it using `IndexError`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more robust approach would be to tap into the traceback object returned by `sys.exc_info()`, extract the code indicated by the file name and line number from the frame, use `ast.parse` to parse the line, subclass `ast.NodeVisitor` to find all the `Subscript` nodes, unparse (with [`astunparse`](https://github.com/simonpercivall/astunparse)) and eval the nodes with the frame's global and local variables to see which of the nodes causes exception, and print the offending expression:

```
import sys
import linecache
import ast
import astunparse

def find_index_error():
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    frame = tb.tb_frame
    lineno = tb.tb_lineno
    filename = frame.f_code.co_filename
    line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, frame.f_globals)
    class find_index_error_node(ast.NodeVisitor):
        def visit_Subscript(self, node):
            expr = astunparse.unparse(node).strip()
            try:
                eval(expr, frame.f_globals, frame.f_locals)
            except IndexError:
                print("%s causes IndexError" % expr)
    find_index_error_node().visit(ast.parse(line.strip(), filename))

a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
x, y = 1, 2
def f():
    return 3
try:
    a[f() - 1] = b[f() + y] + a[x + 1] # can you guess which of them causes IndexError?
except IndexError:
    find_index_error()
```

This outputs:

```
b[(f() + y)] causes IndexError
```

Comment: Nice. Perhaps you could edit this answer so that everything in the `except` block is in a function that can be used whenever the developer needs to unpick what caused an `IndexError`?

Comment: Sure. Edited as suggested then.

Answer (score 9):

There is a way, but I wouldn't consider it as very robust. There is a subtle difference in the error messages:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]

a[2] = b[3]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-8e0d280b609d> in <module>()
      2 b = [1,2,3]
      3 
----> 4 a[2] = b[3]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

But if the error is on the left hand side:

```
a[3] = b[2]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-9d66e07bc70d> in <module>()
      2 b = [1,2,3]
      3 
----> 4 a[3] = b[2]

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Note the 'assignment' in the message.

So, you could do something like:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]

try:
    a[3] = b[2]
except IndexError as e:
    message = e.args[0]
    if 'assignment' in message:
        print("Error on left hand side")
    else:
        print("Error on right hand side")
```

Output:

```
# Error on left hand side
```

Again, I wouldn't trust it too much, it would fail if the message changes in another version of Python.

---

I had a look at [these parts of the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?q=%22list+assignment+index+out+of+range%22&unscoped_q=%22list+assignment+index+out+of+range%22), these different messages are really the only difference between the two errors.

Comment: Also, the assignment is never reached in the first. You cannot differentiate the third case where both would raise an error.

Comment: @schwobaseggl That's right, as the right hand side is evaluated first, it is where the error would be raised.

Comment: good spot! and i totally agree this should not be relied on though as an implementation detail

Answer (score 5):

The `IndexError` exception does not store information about what raised the exception. Its only data is an error message. You have to craft your code to do so.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]

x, y = get_values_from_somewhere()

try:
    value = b[y]
except IndexError as e:
   ...

try:
    a[x] = value
except IndexError as e:
    ...
```

I want to add I tried to recover the culprit through `inspect.frame` and was unable to do so. Thus I suspect there really is no robust way.

Finally, note that this is specific to `IndexError` as other exceptions may contain the needed information to infer what caused them. By example a `KeyError` contains the key that raised it.

Comment: Knowing the key might still not be enough, e.g. `x = a[key] + b[key]`.

Comment: Totally agree with this independent inspection and validation. It makes life easier

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4]
x = 5
y = 1

try:
    a[x] = b[y]
except IndexError:
    try:
        a[x]
        print('b caused indexerror')
    except IndexError:
        print('a caused indexerror')
```

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no way of deducing which of the two is out of bounds using the IndexError thrown.